# Determine whether the given set is bounded and find its supremum and its infimum.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

Let $A = \{x \mid \Bbb R \mid x^2 \lt 2\}$. Is the set $A$ bounded?
If yes, find its supremum and its infimum.

**Attempt:**
Notice that
\begin{align*}
A &= \{x \in \Bbb R \mid x^2 \lt 2 \} \\
&= \{x \in \Bbb R \mid x^2 - 2 \lt 0 \} \\
&= \{x \in \Bbb R \mid (x - \sqrt{2})(x + \sqrt{2}) \lt 0 \} \\
&= \{x \in \Bbb R \mid -\sqrt{2} \lt x \lt \sqrt{2} \} \\
&= (-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}).
\end{align*}
Hence, by definition, $A$ is bounded. Now, I claim $\sup A = \sqrt{2}$ and $\inf A = -\sqrt{2}$ which is true, indeed. For the supremum, let $M$ be the another upper bound of $A$ and suppose $M \lt \sqrt{2}$.
Then, since $A$ is bounded, there exist an element of $A$, say $r$, such that
$M \lt r$. A contradiction with the definition of an upper bound, that's $M$. Hence, we must have
$\sqrt{2} \le M$ i.e. $\sup A = \sqrt{2}$.

Now, for the infimum, let $m$ be the another lower bound of $A$ and suppose
$-\sqrt{2} \lt m$.
Then, since $A$ is bounded, there exist an element of $A$, say $s$, such that
$s \lt m$. A contradiction with the definition of a lower bound, that's $m$. Hence, we must have
$m \le -\sqrt{2}$ i.e. $\inf A = -\sqrt{2}$.

Am I true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly right, but I think you should be a little more explicit about where you get the contradiction from. In particular, how do you know that there is an element $r \in A$ such that $M<r$? This doesn't come from the fact that $A$ is bounded, it's because $M < \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: And so, where does it come from sir ?

Comment: You could find an example of such an $r$ explicitly. For example, suppose $M< \sqrt{2}$ and let $r=\frac{M+\sqrt{2}}{2}$. Then $r^2 < 2$ so $r \in A$, but $M<r$ which contradicts the assumption that $M$ is an upper bound of $A$.

Comment: Well, nice. Thanks sir for the correction